# LVM2 builtin raid - how to check raid status

Tags: 12.10, raid, lvm

I just created LVM2 builtin RAID1 (something like lvm mirrir, but newer) with `lvconvert --type raid1 -m1 /dev/ubuntu/root /dev/sdb5`, Ubuntu 12.10.

How can I check mirror status/health both in command-mode and in GUI from non-root?

There are my `vgs`, `pvs`, `lvs` (root-only, needed to open /dev/mapper/control):

```
# vgs
 VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
 ubuntu    2   2   0 wz--n- 27.52g  916.00m
# pvs
 PV        VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
 /dev/sda5 ubuntu lvm2 a--  13.76g 408.00m
 /dev/sdb5 ubuntu lvm2 a--  13.76g 508.00m
# lvs
 LV     VG     Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy%  Convert
 root   ubuntu rwi-aom-  13.26G                            100.00
 swap_1 ubuntu -wi-ao-- 100.00m
# lvs -a
 LV              VG     Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy%  Convert
 root            ubuntu rwi-aom-  13.26G                            100.00
 [root_rimage_0] ubuntu iwi-aor-  13.26G
 [root_rimage_1] ubuntu iwi-aor-  13.26G
 [root_rmeta_0]  ubuntu ewi-aor-   4.00m
 [root_rmeta_1]  ubuntu ewi-aor-   4.00m
 swap_1          ubuntu -wi-ao-- 100.00m
```

My `/proc/mdstat` is empty:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
unused devices: <none>
#
```

There are files from my `/dev/mapper`, most are symlinks to dm-*:

```
control
ubuntu-root -> ../dm-4
ubuntu-root_rimage_0 -> ../dm-1
ubuntu-root_rimage_1 -> ../dm-3
ubuntu-root_rmeta_0 -> ../dm-0
ubuntu-root_rmeta_0 -> ../dm-2
ubuntu-swap_1 -> ../dm-5
```

There are messages from my dmesg:

```
md/raid1:mdX: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
created bitmap (14 pages) for device mdX
mdX: bitmap initialized from disk: read 1 pages, set 42 of 27152 bits
EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

(Is it normal that some bits are set in bitmap? )

My `dmsetup` (root only too):

```
# dmsetup table
ubuntu-root_rimage_1: 0 27803648 linear 8:21 10240
ubuntu-root_rimage_0: 0 27803648 linear 8:5 2048
ubuntu-swap_1: 0 204800 linear 8:5 27805696
ubuntu-root: 0 27803648 raid raid1 3 0 region_size 1024 2 252:0 252:1 252:2 252:3
ubuntu-root_rmeta_1: 0 8192 linear 8:21 2048
ubuntu-root_rmeta_0: 0 8192 linear 8:5 28010496
```

(is my raid setup correct?)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand,

```
lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices yourvgname
```

will show less than 100% in the copy_percent column if your RAID devices are not in sync yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but as I am currently moving to lvm-raid my best conclusion so far is to use:

```
lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,health_status,devices vgroup
```

As this would provide %sync and health_status which I understand would be empty if all correct.